# Transparent Google Map on PopupWindow?

Tags: android, google-maps, popup

I have used a Google Maps (V2) in a `PopupWindow` and when I run the application, the map is not displayed. Even the area where it should be is fully transparent and I can see the activity below the `PopupWindow` through it.

Any idea why this is?

**Fragment inside popup_window.xml**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/popup_alert_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/popup_alert_description"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

**And how I show it inside Popup.java**

```
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.popup_alert_map);
locationMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();

locationMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
locationMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
```

I have another `Activity` with a map it it and *that* displays nicely.

Any help greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `SupportMapFragment` then you should use the `SupportFragmentManager`, like this:

```
locationMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.popup_alert_map)).getMap();
```

Try this, tell me what the result.

Comment: Did that, still the same... :(

Comment: Nope, no error. Only that the area where the Map should be is fully transparent- I can see the other side of the PopupWindow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug, either in Android or in the `MapFragment`/`SupportMapFragment`. I tried the same thing (adding the Google Map fragment in a `PopupWindow`) and on a Google Nexus 10 with Android 4.4, and the map appeared on the `PopupWindow` just fine, but on an older device with Android 4.0.3 it showed the transparency problem.

Eventually what I did was just move it to another `Activity`. I looked for as many ways as I could to fix it but it all seems like a dead end, especially given the fact that it works on the newest version of Android without any problems.